# phpcassa returns less number of records with columns

Tags: php, cassandra, phpcassa

I am making the multiget call to cassandra with  PHPCASSA. Its functioning properly except one of the case. When I query the Cassandra with Column names it returns less number of column with values.
     e.g. for row1 => { col1=>1,col2=>2,col3=>3,col4=>4}
I am making call multiget with (col1,col2,col3) then it returns col1 with value. col2,col3 are not returned.

I am clueless whether this is issue on the Cassandra side OR PHPCASSA side.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance
Manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our team working on the Cassandra did some RND around this issue and figured out that it is issue with Cassandra 1.2 and older version. Cassandra stops reading row once row size grows beyond 64 KB if we are selecting particular columns. If user selects complete row then it works fine.